# Updating Button image once is selected iPad not working

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-data

I am trying to make my image update once a new on is selected.
The update works but it does not show up right away when the new image is selected during editing and I was wondering if anyone has any idea how to fix it.

The app was originally created for iPhone and this function works fine, the image is updated as soon as a new one is selected even during editing for the iPhone, but when I use it on the iPad the image does not change during editing but once I finish the editing and go back, I can see the image is change.

I am making the core data recipe sample code from the developer center to work on the iPad.

This is my code for selecting a new Image PhotoTapped1 button, this has been change to work with the iPad:

```
- (IBAction)photoTapped1 {
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()== UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
// If in editing state, then display an image picker; if not, create and push a photo view controller.
    if (self.editing) {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
        [imagePicker release];
    } else {
        RecipePhotoViewController *recipePhotoViewController = [[RecipePhotoViewController alloc] init];
        recipePhotoViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
        recipePhotoViewController.recipe = recipe;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:recipePhotoViewController animated:YES];
        [recipePhotoViewController release];
    }
}else{
    if (self.editing){
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
        [self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 400) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
        self.popover.delegate = self;
        [popover release];
    }else{
         RecipePhotoViewController *recipePhotoViewController = [[RecipePhotoViewController alloc] init];
         recipePhotoViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
         recipePhotoViewController.recipe = recipe;
         [self.navigationController pushViewController:recipePhotoViewController animated:YES];
         [recipePhotoViewController release];
    }}}
```

This is working fine and the image is update on, but not during editing.
During editing it shows the image that was there all along, so it can be confusing as anyone using the app can not be sure if the new selected image has been added or updated.

The following is the imagePickerController and the updateButton code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)selectedImage editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {

// Delete any existing image.
NSManagedObject *oldImage = recipe.image;
if (oldImage != nil) {
    [recipe.managedObjectContext deleteObject:oldImage];
}

// Create an image object for the new image.
NSManagedObject *image = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Image" inManagedObjectContext:recipe.managedObjectContext];
recipe.image = image;

// Set the image for the image managed object.
[image setValue:selectedImage forKey:@"image"];

// Create a thumbnail version of the image for the recipe object.
CGSize size = selectedImage.size;
CGFloat ratio = 0;
if (size.width > size.height) {
    ratio = 44.0 / size.width;
} else {
    ratio = 44.0 / size.height;
}
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, ratio * size.width, ratio * size.height);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
[selectedImage drawInRect:rect];
recipe.thumbnailImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];}
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: nil];
}
```

Here is the updatePhotoButton:

```
   - (void)updatePhotoButton {
/* How to present the photo button depends on the editing state and whether the     recipe has a thumbnail image.
 * If the recipe has a thumbnail, set the button's highlighted state to the same as the editing state (it's highlighted if editing).
 * If the recipe doesn't have a thumbnail, then: if editing, enable the button and show an image that says "Choose Photo" or similar; if not editing then disable the button and show nothing.  
 */
BOOL editing = self.editing;

if (recipe.thumbnailImage != nil) {
    photoButton.highlighted = editing;
} else {
    photoButton.enabled = editing;

    if (editing) {
        [photoButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"choosePhoto.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [photoButton setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
    }
```

Does anyone has any idea what would be the problem? I know the UIImagePickerControll has to be used with UIPopoverController in order to work on the iPad, but that is being updated on the -(IBAction)PhotoTapped1 code.

Not sure where to go from here.

Thank you.

Update to question..

PhotoViewController.h

```
@class Recipe;

@interface RecipePhotoViewController : UIViewController {
@private
    Recipe *recipe;
    UIImageView *imageView;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) Recipe *recipe;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *imageView;

@end
```

RecipePhotoViewController.m

```
#import "RecipePhotoViewController.h"

#import "Recipe.h"

@implementation RecipePhotoViewController

@synthesize recipe;
@synthesize imageView;

- (void)loadView {
self.title = @"Photo";

 imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame];
 imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
 imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
 imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

 self.view = imageView;
 }


 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  imageView.image = [recipe.image valueForKey:@"image"];
 }


  - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:    (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
   return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
   }


- (void)dealloc {
 [imageView release];
 [recipe release];
 [super dealloc];
  }


 @end
```

This is an updated data to original question

Comment: Only use the [tag:Xcode] tag for questions about the IDE itself. Thanks!

Comment: Where are you setting the image? This code only ever sets the image to "choosePhoto" or nil. Is it done in a viewWillAppear (or some such) and that is why you only see it when you go back?

Comment: Hi Mike, I have added the RecipePhotoViewControllers in the original question, Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason there's no problem on iPhone is that the previous image isn't visible on iPhone, because you're using a presented view controller: the image picker takes over the entire screen. On iPad, on the other hand, you're using a popover, so the main interface is still visible behind the popover. Thus the user is able to see that the image being tapped is not the image that appears back in the main interface.

But might argue that there's no problem with this. The user hasn't actually accepted the image yet, until the image picker popover is dismissed. You say:

> During editing it shows the image that was there all along, so it can be confusing as anyone using the app can not be sure if the new selected image has been added or updated.

But what if the user taps outside the popover to dismiss / cancel it? Surely you wouldn't want the image to have changed in the main interface. The behavior you're objecting to, therefore, is right: you're complaining that the image in the main interface is not updated until the popover is actually dismissed, and that's exactly how it should be. When the user is working in a popover, what's going on behind the popover is irrelevant.

Comment: Hello Matt, Thank you for the explanation, I get it.